# alembic for sqlalchemy doesn't detect column additions and removals

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, migration

I defined the flowing model.

```
class JjfqServiceProvidorRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'jjfq_service_providor_record'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    phone = Column(String(16))
    name = Column(String(20))
```

Then I ran `alembic revision --autogenerate -m 'first'`, and got the flowing migration file:

```
def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('jjfq_service_providor_record',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('phone', sa.String(length=16), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=20), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
    ### end Alembic commands ###

def downgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_table('jjfq_service_providor_record')
    ### end Alembic commands ###
```

And then, I delete the `name` field like this:

```
class JjfqServiceProvidorRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'jjfq_service_providor_record'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    phone = Column(String(16))
    name = Column(String(20))
```

Then I reran `alembic revision --autogenerate -m 'second'`, the migration file generated by this command turn out to be:

```
def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    pass
    ### end Alembic commands ###
```

What's wrong? Why didn't alembic detect column additions and removals?

> python    : Python 2.7.5
>   alembic   : latest verison
>   sqlalchemy: 1.0
>   framework : falcon
>   system    : Debian GNU/Linux 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, Finally I found the problem. My sys.path point to the wrong directory where is an old version of my code. So every time I ran `alembic revision --autogenerate`, it reads from the old code which wasn't modified.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll describe my environment:

```
OS X El Capitan
MySQL Server 5.7
alembic (0.8.6)
PyMySQL (0.7.2)
SQLAlchemy (1.0.12)
```

This is my directory structure after installing and initializing Alembic:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── alembic
│   ├── README
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
├── alembic.ini
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── models.py
└── requirements.txt

3 directories, 9 files
```

I've defined the model in `app/models.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class JjfqServiceProvidorRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'jjfq_service_providor_record'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    phone = Column(String(16))
    name = Column(String(20))
```

For `alembic/env.py`, I have the following:

```
from app import *
from app.models import Base
target_metadata = Base.metadata
```

After that, I ran the autogeneration command:

```
$ alembic revision --autogenerate -m 'first'
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'jjfq_service_providor_record'
  Generating /tmp/37027017/alembic/versions/5b157ced3fa0_first.py ... done
```

The first migration file should look like this:

```
"""first

Revision ID: 5b157ced3fa0
Revises: 
Create Date: 2016-05-05 21:53:57.687433

"""

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '5b157ced3fa0'
down_revision = None
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('jjfq_service_providor_record',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('phone', sa.String(length=16), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=20), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
    ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_table('jjfq_service_providor_record')
    ### end Alembic commands ###
```

If you're satisfied with how the first migration file looks, run the upgrade migration:

```
$ alembic upgrade head
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> 5b157ced3fa0, first
```

After that, you can remove the `jjfq_service_providor_record.name` column from the table definition in `app/models.py`, and run a second autogeneration:

```
$ alembic revision --autogenerate -m 'second'
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed column 'jjfq_service_providor_record.name'
  Generating /tmp/37027017/alembic/versions/acbba548b6cd_second.py ... done
```

The second migration file should look like this:

```
"""second

Revision ID: acbba548b6cd
Revises: 5b157ced3fa0
Create Date: 2016-05-05 21:55:23.130404

"""

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = 'acbba548b6cd'
down_revision = '5b157ced3fa0'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql

def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_column('jjfq_service_providor_record', 'name')
    ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.add_column('jjfq_service_providor_record', sa.Column('name', mysql.VARCHAR(length=20), nullable=True))
    ### end Alembic commands ###
```

If that also looks good, run the second migration and you should be all set!

```
$ alembic upgrade head
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 5b157ced3fa0 -> acbba548b6cd, second
```

As you saw, the comment "second" in my second revision was deliberate, it helped me more accurately catalog exactly where in the process the removal of the `name` column was. I think it makes it clearer when you're trying to determine the migration history.

Hope that helped!

Comment: How could you define jjfq_service_providor_record in base.py and remove jjfq_service_providor_record.name in model.py?

Comment: @dae Please let me know if my answer is satisfactory. If not, please include why. Thanks.

Comment: I followed your step. But the second migrations was still empty. I've update my question. @John A.

Comment: @dae Hmm...that's interesting. Try `alembic current` to see what it says. It should point to the `head` in this case, the second revision `acbba548b6cd`. If all else fails, you should try deleting the `alembic_version` database table and starting from the beginning.

Comment: Oh,  I know why. My sys.path point to the wrong directory where is an old version of my code. Thanks for you Answer. @John A.

Comment: Glad you were able to find it!